# How create text label of form "var = ", var properly formatted

Tags: formatting, text

If I use

```
   z = 99;
   Row[{TraditionalForm@HoldForm[z == 1], z}]
```

then as output I get a property formatted math expression $z = 199$.

How do I accomplish the same thing without having that `1` after `==`?

In other words, I want to be able to crate a `Row` expression that will display a properly formatted math expression of the form $\text{varName} = \text{varValue}$?

The issue is subtler than it may first seem. The real difficulty is getting the equal sign to appear as normal size, not longer than it should be (as using `==` might cause) and to have proper, typographically correct, spacing before and after the equal sign.

Of course, a good solution should generalize to more complicated expressions, such as producing typographically correct expressions as $\sin(2 \pi z) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ after setting `z = 1/8`.

Comment: `z = 99; StringForm["z = ``", z] // TraditionalForm`

Comment: `z = 99; DisplayForm[FormBox[RowBox[{"z", "=", z}], TraditionalForm]]`?

Comment: `TraditionalForm@Row[{HoldForm[z], " = ", z }]`

Comment: The trouble with things like `TraditionalForm@Row[{HoldForm[z], " = ", z }]` is that the `" = "` part is pure text and doesn't produce reasonable mathematical typography -- too much space around the equal sign.

Comment: @J.M.: your solution does give proper spacing appropriate to good mathematical typography. Alas, it doesn't seem to generalize to typesetting things like $\sin(2 \pi z) = 1/\sqrt{2}$ after setting `z=1/8`.

Comment: Question: output like $\sin\left(2\pi\;\frac18\right)$ would be considered unsatisfactory, no?

Comment: @J.M.: correct, on the left-hand side of the equality, the variable's name should appear, not its value; its value is involved only on the right-hand side of the equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do something like this:

```
z = 99;
Row[{TraditionalForm@HoldForm[z == ""], z}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This typesets OK -- *provided that* you change `==` to `=`.

Answer (score 6):

You might try this.

```
SetAttributes[label, HoldFirst];
label[var_Symbol] :=
  Module[{textForm},
    textForm = First @ StringSplit[SymbolName[Unevaluated[var]], "$"];
    TraditionalForm @
      ToExpression[textForm <> "==" <> ToString[var], StandardForm, HoldForm]]
```

Then

```
z = 42; label[z]
```

gives

[image: z-out]

It also handles this

```
z = Sin[2 π t]; label[z]
```

[image: sin-out]

and this

```
Module[{z = 42}, label[z]]
```

[image: z-out]

Comment: The equal sign from label[z] comes out too long, not like a proper equal sign in mathematical typography.

Comment: @murray. You specified "==" in your question, and that's the glyph you get from _Mathematica_ in traditional form to represent "==". Try specifying "=" instead. You may like the results better.

Comment: Yes, that will work with `=` instead of `==`. I had not tried the former. But the answer by Michael E2 seems a lot simpler.

Comment: @murray. Michael's answer ***is*** simpler and if it meets your needs, use it. My answer is more general; it works inside `Module`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use `HoldForm` in concert with `Set`/`=` in order to get the typesetting you want, and use `HoldFirst` to capture the expression, while `With` substitutes in the value?

```
Attributes[EquationForm] = {HoldFirst};
EquationForm[expr_] :=
 With[{value = expr},
  TraditionalForm[HoldForm[expr = value]];
```

Then you can enter:

```
z = 1/8;
EquationForm[Sin[2*Pi*z]]
```

and get

> [image: typeset equation]

Comment: In my situation, the variable `z` already has a value, so using a `Rule` would require, I think, awkward multiple replacements.